# Trying to Wrap My Head Around String Sizes in C

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

A friend and I are doing a C programming unit for college.

We understand that there is no "string" per se in C, and instead, a string is defined by being an array of characters.  Awesome!

So when dealing with "strings" is obvious that a proper understanding arrays and pointers is important.

We were doing really well understanding pointer declaration, when and when not to dereference the pointer, and played around with a number of `printf`'s to test our experiments. All with great success.

However, when we used this:

```
char *myvar = "";
myvar = "dhjfejfdhdkjfhdjkfhdjkfhdjfhdfhdjhdsjfkdhjdfhddskjdkljdklc";
printf("Size is %d\n", sizeof(myvar));
```

and it spits out `Size is 8`!

Why 8?  Clearly there are more than 8 bytes being consumed by 'myvar' (or is it)?

(I should be clear and point out that I am VERY aware of 'strlen'.  This is not an exercise in getting the length of a string.  This is about trying to understand why sizeof returns 8 bytes for the variable myvar.)

Comment: what size did you expect, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

8 is the size of the pointer.
myvar is a pointer to char (hence char*) and in 64 bit system pointers are 64 bit = 8 byte

To get size of a null-terminated string use this code :

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *x="hello there";
printf("%d\n",strlen(x));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is bugous since you should allocate space first then set it, or use char *myvar="string here";

Comment: He doesn't need to allocate space. But he should use "const char *" instead as string literals are stored in a read-only portion of memory usually. But there's not need to over-complicate this with allocating memory.

Comment: also for const char* you should initialize the string via = initilization operator (which is totally different from = assignment operator) thus assigning in a different line is a memory violation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on code guys, but this is a higher level question - code is semi-irrelevant in the example - I'm just trying to understand it conceptually, and no I understand why - because the memory address on a 64bit machine is a bigint.  Doh! I didnt even think of that!

Although, I thought a pointer was more than just a memory address, doesn't the pointer also contain additional information?

Comment: that's the length rather than the size

Comment: An interesting note is that using sizeof("abcd") will return 5.  It returns the actual number of bytes including NULL that the string requires.  so sizeof("abcd") and strlen("abcd)+1 are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Well as AbiusX said, the reason why sizeof is returning 8 is because you are finding the size of a pointer (and I'm guessing you're on a 64-bit machine). For example, that same code-snippet would return 4 on my machine.

Strings in C are kept as an array of characters followed by a null terminator. So when you do this...

```
const char *message = "hello, world!"
```

It's actually stored in memory as:

```
'h''e''l''l''o'','' ''w''o''r''l''d''!''\0'...garbage here
```

If you read past the null terminator, you'll likely just find whatever garbage happens to be in memory there at the time. So in order to find the length of a string in C, you need to start at the beginning of the string and read until the null terminator.

```
size_t count = 0;
const char *message = "hello, world!";
for ( ; message[count] != '\0'; count++ );
printf("size of message %u\n", count);
```

Now this is an O(n) operation (because you have to iterate over the entire array to get the size). Most higher level languages have their upper level abstraction of strings as something similar to...

```
struct string {
    char *c_str;
    size_t length;
};
```

And then they just keep track of how long the string is whenever they do an operation on it. This greatly speeds up finding the length of a string, which is a very common operation.

Now there is one way you can figure out the length of a string using sizeof, but I don't suggest it. Using sizeof on an array (not a pointer!) will return the size of the array multiplied by the data type size. And C can auto-figure out the size of an array as long as it can be figured out at compile-time.

```
const char message[] = "hello, world!";
printf("size of message %u\n", sizeof(message));
```

That will print the correct size of the message. Remember, this is NOT suggested. Notice that this will print one greater than the number of characters in the string. That's because it also counts the null terminator (as it has to allocate an array large enough to have the null terminator). So it's not really the real length of the string (you can always just subtract one).

Answer (score 0):

`myvar` is a pointer. You seem to be on a 64-bit machine, so `sizeof` returns 8 byte in size. What you're probably looking for instead is [strlen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/).

Answer (score 0):

Like AbiusX said, 8 is the size of the pointer. `strlen` can tell you the length of the string ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)).